# understanding $K_1(\mathbb{Z}[G])$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I was looking for following theorem of Bass:

> **Theorem:** *Let $G$ be finite group and let $j:\mathcal{U} (\mathbb{Z}[G])\rightarrow K_1(\mathbb{Z}[G])$ denote the natural map. The images of Bass cyclic units of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ generate a subgroup of finite index in $K_1(\mathbb{Z}[G])$.*

Here domain of $j$ is group of units in group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$.

I don't know the technical definition of $K_1(\mathbb{Z}[G])$; it is related to $K$-theory with which I am not so familiar. In Wiki, there is long article on $K$-theory [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_K-theory), from which I was not exactly extracting what $K_1(\mathbb{Z}[G])$ stands for? It is defined for general rings also, but I first want to understand it for just $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ and see some examples.

**Q.** What is simplest way to define $K_1(\mathbb{Z}[G])$? Some elementary examples to be kept in mind always?

Comment: [It says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_K-theory#K1) that if $A$ is a ring, $K_1(A)$ is the abelianization of the infinite general linear group.

Comment: so for non-abelian group $Z[G]$ is non-commutative ring, and so general linear group over it is defined *not using determinants*, am I right?

Comment: I suggest you browse Rosenberg's book *Introduction to algebraic K-theory*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Is there a simple motivating example (for $A$ or $G$) for looking at this group $K_1$ ?

Comment: Rosenberg's book gives all the motivating examples that I can think of (class groups of Dedekind rings, Whiteahead groups of spaces, and so on). I really don't think writing here a short and bad version is a good idea.